# Problem while retrieving Button tags

Tags: iphone, ipad

my app requirements are as follows:-

1.) Make a Buttton  according to Number of images store in a library.(i have done it).
2.) Disable all buttons when user click on Disable Button.
to full fill the second requirement i set the tag of each button at the time of creation:

```
button.setTag=tag;
```

where tag increase on e by one.

problem is that when i disable button it disable only last button.how can i acess button tag value one by one.?

```
for (int index = 0; index < [objectButtonArray count];index++) { 
    UIButton *button = [objectButtonArray objectAtIndex:index]; 
    button.hidden = NO; 
    imageButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO; 
}
```

Comment: A bit more context would help. How are you disabling the button. And it is `button.tag = tag`.

Comment: button.tag = tag but it give only last button tag value

Comment: Can you show the code where you are disabling the button?

Comment: for (int index = 0; index < [objectButtonArray count];index++)
  {
   UIButton *button = [objectButtonArray objectAtIndex:index];
   button.hidden = NO;
   imageButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
  }

Comment: Rahul, you please edit your question and provide code snippets there..Not put code in comments

Comment: @Rahul it looks like you're adding the same element or adding just one element to your array. Can you show you're doing it?

Comment: @Rahul Can you show the code where you are adding buttons to `objectButtonArray`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way....

```
for (UIView *view in yourView.subviews) {

                        [view viewWithTag:BUTTON_TAG].userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                    }
```

Comment: itzme can you explain for (UIView *view in yourView.subviews) . i can't understand it. please .

Comment: its enumerating the subviews of your mainView

Comment: Your buttons are the subviews of your main view, you will get all subviews by this code....

Comment: Add a logic to iterate button tag inside this code, and replace this value for BUTTON_TAG...

Answer (score 1):

Either use `button.tag = tag;` or `[button setTag:tag];`. Your line `button.setTag=tag;` does not do what you think it does (unless you think it's nonsense).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    for (int index = minTag; index <= maxTag;index++) { 
        UIView *aView = [self.view viewWithTag:index];
        if ([aView isKindOfClass:[UIButton Class]]) {
             [aView setUserInterationEnabled:NO];
         }
    }
```